# cannot be cast to java.lang.String autocomplete primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com esse problema vários dias e não consigo resolver. Estou usando autocomplete do primefaces para buscar os clientes cadastrados no meu sistema. Já fiz meu converter, segui um tutorial e meu não funciona.

Meu  `xhtml` que está dentro de um dialog:

```
                <p:outputLabel value="Cliente" for="cliente"/>
                <p:autoComplete id="cliente" size="40" dropdown="true" 
                                value="#{cadastroPrazoBean.prazo.cliente}" 
                                completeMethod="#{cadastroPrazoBean.completarCliente}"
                                var="c" itemLabel="#{c.nome}"
                                itemValue="#{c}" forceSelection="true" />
```

Complete cliente:

```
 public List<Cliente> completarCliente(String nome) {
    return clientes.buscaPorNome(nome);
}
```

Busca por nome:

```
 public List<Cliente> buscaPorNome(String nome) {
    Session session = this.manager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cliente.class);

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(nome)) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("nome", nome.toUpperCase(), MatchMode.START));
    }
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Converter cliente:

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

@FacesConverter(forClass = Cliente.class)
public class ClienteConverter implements Converter {



@Inject
private Clientes clientes;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,     String value) {
    Cliente retorno = null;

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
        retorno = this.clientes.porId(new Long(value));
    }
    return retorno;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,    Object value) {
    if (value != null) {
        Long codigo = ((Cliente) value).getId();
        String retorno = (codigo == null ? null : codigo.toString());

        return retorno;
    }

    return "";
}
```

`}`

Erro completo:

```
Grave:   Erro de sistema: br.com.sistemajuridico.model.Cliente cannot be       cast to java.lang.String
 java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.sistemajuridico.model.Cliente cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at   org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestionsAsLi     st(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:553)
 at   org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestions(Aut      oCompleteRenderer.java:435)
    at  org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeResults(AutoCom     pleteRenderer.java:130)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeEnd(AutoComplet     eRenderer.java:112)
    at       javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
  at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(Parti      alViewContextImpl.java:582)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:432)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Problema do converte foi resolvido, estou com esse erro ao salvar

```
Grave:   Erro de sistema: null
javax.faces.FacesException
at   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPha    se.java:84)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.com.sistemajuridico.converter.ClienteConverter.getAsObject(ClienteConverter.java:30)
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.getConvertedValue(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:670)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at org.primefaces.component.dialog.Dialog.processValidators(Dialog.java:423)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
... 59 more
```

Comment: Suspeito que seja algo no seu converter. Faça o seguinte teste: Na classe  `ClienteConverter` substitua `@FacesConverter(forClass = Cliente.class)` por `@FacesConverter("ConverterTeste")` e adicione no atributo `converter` do autocomplete ficando assim `<p:autoComplete ... converter="ConverterTeste"`.

Comment: Outra coisa também é verificar se na sua classe `Cliente` os métodos `hashCode` e `equals` estão implementados e se o `toString` está retornando o id do objeto.

Comment: @hebertrfreitas Deu certo! Muito Obrigado. Esta trazendo as informações agora. Estava com dois problemas. Minha classe Cliente não estava  com `hashCode` e `equals`, no meu converter fiz oque você falou e deu certo parou o erro.

Comment: @hebertrfreitas Estou com erro ao salvar. Postei o código na pergunta. Coloca sua resposta para eu marcar como resolvido. vlw

Comment: @SidneiFerreira Qual a linha citada no código do NullPointerException?

Comment: @mutlei Da minha  classe converter, está na pergunta

Comment: Qual a linha específica? A contagem do exemplo que tu citou e a do log não coincidem.

Comment: @mutlei linha 30: `retorno = this.clientes.porId(new Long(value));`

Comment: @SidneiFerreira Você usa o id com o tipo primitivo `long` ou com o wrapper `Long`? Se for com o tipo primitivo, a entrada do parâmetro deve ser com um Long.parseLong. Caso contrário, não sei.

Comment: @mutlei Uso wrapper. `private Long id;` Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Então eu acho que problema é esse: você está usando um objeto pra cadastrar o cliente, quando você vai buscar, cria um outro objeto, logo o cliente não é resgatado, pois esse segundo não está no registro de clientes.

Comment: @mutlei Poderia usar um relacionamento entre tabelas nesse caso?

Comment: @SidneiFerreira Acho que sim, se fizer um `Select` pode conseguir os dados do cliente e procurá-lo a partir disso. Mas nunca criando um objeto.

Comment: @mutlei  Nessa minha classe prazo, vai ter um relacionamento entre prazo  e advogado, um ManyToMany. vou fazer um relacionamento entre cliente tbm.  Poderia me ajudar a salvar  esse relacionamento? fazendo um grande favor!

Comment: @mutlei Como posso buscar esse advogado e salvar? Tenho alguns metodos: `List<Advogado> buscaPorNome` , `public Advogado porId(Long id)`  Na minha classe prazo iria salvar assim: `value="#{cadastroPrazoBean.advogado.nome}"`.

Comment: @SidneiFerreira Eu faria um select usando apenas o `id` do Cliente/Advogado, pegando todos os atributos e montaria o objeto na função, mas não é a melhor ideia. A minha sugestão é parar de usar o wrapper nos IDs, pois só vai trazer complicação. Usa as classes para métodos auxiliares, mas valores, use os tipos primitivos, sempre que possível.

Comment: @mutlei Muito obrigado pelas dicas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente trata-se de algum erro no converter, tente fazer o seguinte
Na classe `ClienteConverter` substitua `@FacesConverter(forClass = Cliente.class)` por `@FacesConverter("ConverterTeste")` e adicione no atributo converter do autocomplete ficando assim `<p:autoComplete ... converter="ConverterTeste"`.

Caso queira uma abordagem mais genérica futuramente você poderá experimentar um converter genérico que funcionaria para todas as suas entidades como o apresentado neste link: [Converters genéricos](http://www.rponte.com.br/2008/07/26/entity-converters-pra-da-e-vender/)

Além disso verifique se na sua classe `Cliente` os métodos `hashCode` e `equals` estão implementados e se o `toString` está retornando o id do objeto.